# How to find the lowest key in a dictionary without built in functions

Tags: python

I have a task to find the lowest key in a dictionary so an example problem is
{“1”:3,”2”:1,”6”:2,”4”:3} so first I find which one have the highest value for this it would be 3 and since 3 appears twice I have to find which key is the lowest. I think I know how this would be done if I was looking for the largest

```
Large=0
For i in dic:
   V=dic[i]
   If v > large:
       Large=v
Return large
```

How can I change this to find the lowest without using built in functions

Comment: Sorry, what’s your question exactly? You said you want a solution with no builtin functions, but you didn’t use any in your code snippit.

Comment: How about `print(min(dic.keys()))` = 1 = lowest key?

Comment: @anonymous4045 that’s what I think would find the largest key I want to know if there’s something like that to find the lowest key

Comment: @Nothanks change the `>` to a `<` lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_my_dict = {"1":3, "2":1, "6":2, "4":3, "4": 2}
# Using list comprehension and iterating only through keys
# and then getting the min
lowest_key = min([int(key) for key in _my_dict.keys()])
print(lowest_key)
####
1
```

Comment: Nice code, please tidy-up your answer, the use of _ is a bit much